# Why does javac create <init> method in class that doesn't create any instance

Tags: java, constructor, jvm, javac

I have question related with java compiler.

Example code:

```
public class TheClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

When i compile this class i can see in [JavaClassViewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35915/Java-Class-Viewer/), this class contains `<init>` method which invokes `java.lang.Object` construcotr, but i am not creating any instance of this class and no any constructor is called.
[image]
JVM calls static method main, but it doesn't create instance of class. So, why compiler produces `<init>` method? I could understand this if i would create object of `TheClass`

Comment: I think, because of each class have default constructor without parameter. If you do not declare on your code, Java will call it automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The [JLS requires that a default constructor be generated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> 8.8.9. Default Constructor
>
> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared.

Also:

> i am not creating any instance of this class

Irrelevant. The compiler can't know that.

Comment: Thanks for the doc. It's same my understand :D

Answer (score 0):

How do you envision that the compiler would know that you're not doing `new TheClass()` from some other class?

Besides, [JLS 8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) says:

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is implicitly declared.

The compiler is *required* to do so.